# Boudary values concrete example

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Let's suppose we have the following equivalence partitions:

```
|invalid partition A| valid partion B | invalid partition C
...................1|2              10|11................
```

As we see valid partion B is [2..10] (that is including 2 and 10). To test B partion let's take 7. Ok, now let's test boundary values. As we see boundaries are 2 and 10. In some books they say that besides 2 and 10 it is necessary to take additional points +- sigma.

So the question, how many values must we take to test valid partition B three **(2, 7, 10)** or five **(2, 2.01, 7 , 9.99, 10)**?

Answer (score 1):

The definitions of boundary value analysis vary, but they all agree on the following minimum set of test values (for a partition that is closed to both sides): one test case for the minimum, one for the maximum value of a partition.  The same holds, then, for all valid neighboring partitions.  Surprisingly, for invalid partitions only the extreme values adjacent to the valid partitions habe to be tested.  Extending your example:

```
|invalid part. A| valid part. B | valid part. C |invalid part. D|
|1.............9|10           19|20           29|30...........39|
```

For this scenario, the various definitions agree about the need to test for the values 9,10,19,20,29,30.  That is, for B there is not even consensus about whether a 'typical' value like 15 should be tested.

From my point of view, the important question is about what kind of bugs you intend to find.  That is, if you can't think of a scenario where additional tests could bring up additional bugs, the additional tests are useless.

In this light, tests on the boundaries can help to identify mistakes regarding operators <, >, <=, >=, == and, consequently, off-by-one errors.  If your requirement demands a '<' operator (e. g. `if (x < 10) then y := 0 else y := 1`), then testing for 9 and 10 alone will help you detect if mistakenly one of the operators >, <=, >= or == was used.  Alternatively, you could detect if a different value than 10 was used in the comparison.

More challenging is, in practice, to identify all partitions.  If the code example was like `if (x * x < 10) then y := 0 else y := 1`, then suddenly there are quite some more partitions for x, namely the range [-3 ... 3], the ranges for x where x*x will not overflow, and the ranges where x*x will overflow.  It gets more complicated when additional parameters have to be considered, like (x + y < 10).